# Best Practices for Implementing SAML Federation: Should Federating Clients Adhere to IdP or SP SAML Contracts?

Tags: authentication, saml, identity-management

Currently, I'm grappling with a decision regarding the handling of custom attributes in the context of SAML federation. I'm unsure whether to mandate clients to define custom attributes or if I should conform to the attributes they send. Ideally, I'd like to adopt a practice similar to some Identity Providers (IdPs), where clients can provide basic attributes like email, id, surname, etc., but I also want to enforce a unique attribute, like an SSOID, in addition to the typical NameID. Should I insist that clients define this unique attribute, or is it more common to adapt to the attributes they provide? I'm seeking insights into best practices and considerations for this aspect of SAML federation implementation.

Comment: If you need an opaque ID for privacy reasons you can use eduPersonTargetedID (ePTID). Its value is SP specific. Every time the user logs in to the SP, the same value of ePTID is sent. It's a very common attribute.